# Discord.JS, Numbering users that send a specific phrase to Bot DMs

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm making a function in my bot where when a phrase is sent to the bot, it displays that it's the first user to send that phrase, then the second user, it displays second, and so on. As of now I have the for loop so it displays all numbers 1-3 all at once. I am just having some difficulty creating the function to display one number for each user that sends the message.
[For more clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H67dN.png)

Any Help is appreciated, thank you!

Code:

```
        const channel = bot.channels.cache.get('732757852615344139');
    
        channel.updateOverwrite(message.author,{
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
          })     
          for(let i = 1; i< 4; i++){
        let scavWelcome = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Good Work')
          .setDescription(`Welcome ${message.author}, you placed number ${i}`)
          channel.send(scavWelcome)
        }
      }
```

Comment: Have a number in the global scope, each time the phrase is said increment the number, display the number

Comment: So something like: if (message.content == 'Phrase'{
i++
}

Or something along those lines?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you define `i` outside of the message event or else the variable will reset on each message, I'll provide an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a global counter variable along with a max count, either by global variable or hoisting to the bot object. Increment the counter on each message. Once the counter reaches max, reset the counter back to 1.

```
// Under where you defined bot
bot.counter = 1;
bot.maxCount = 4;

bot.on('message', message => {
   // Your message event code...
   
   const channel = bot.channels.cache.get('732757852615344139');
    
   channel.updateOverwrite(message.author,{
       VIEW_CHANNEL: true
   })     

   if (message.content === 'Phrase Here') {
      if (bot.counter === bot.maxCount) bot.counter = 1;
      else bot.counter++;
   }
   
   let scavWelcome = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Good Work')
      .setDescription(`Welcome ${message.author}, you placed number ${bot.counter}`)
   channel.send(scavWelcome);
});
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, I'm always having trouble with global counters, get easily confused with the logistics for some reason haha, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you could use an array to store the users and get the index of the elements which would correspond to their position

```
client.on('message', message => {
const userArr = [];
if (message.content.toLowerCase() == 'a phrase') userArr.push(`${message.author.username`);
});
```

Then you can view the list in appropriate order by doing

```
for (let i = 0; i < userArr.length; i++) arrWithIndex.push(`${i + 1} ${userArr[i]}`) // i + 1 because index starts with 0, but we're counting from 1
message.channel.send(arrWithIndex.join('\n'));
```

if i misinterpreted your question, could you please explain it in the comments, ty

Comment: I see the solution you're going for, that could possibly work, the other fellow's response seemed to have solved the problem, appreciate the response!